# Telegram Bot. Как отправить изображение с сайта? Python

Tags: python, telegram, telebot

```
response = requests.get('https://api.qrserver.com/v1/create-qr-code/?size=150x150&data=Example')

@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])

def selfmyself(message):
    image_data = response.content
    img = Image.open(io.BytesIO(image_data))
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f'{img}')
```

В телеграме бот выдает  следующее `<PIL.PngImagePlugin.PngImageFile image mode=P size=150x150 at 0x19F758B6130>` Как можно решить данную задачку? Помогите пожалуйста

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import os
import urllib.request

@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def selfmyself(message):
     urllib.request.urlretrieve("https://api.qrserver.com/v1/create-qr-code/?size=150x150&data=Example",
                           "files/local-filename.png")

     img = open('files/local-filename.png', 'rb')
     bot.send_photo(message.chat.id, img)
     os.remove('files/local-filename.png')
```

Comment: FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'files/local-filename.png' (

Comment: вы создали каталог files в директории со скриптом?

Comment: Понял, забыл, спасибо)